# Python Tkinter module error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI based program in Python using the Tkinter module .I created a text widget named self.f_text ,but when i invoke the get method on it ,i get a very unusual error .I have checked the code 4 times,i was not able to find any mistake. It would be great if someone can answer my question.

## Custom mad-lib program

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        Label(self,text = "Welcome to medicaps ki pathshala.").grid(row = 0,column = 0,columnspan = 2,sticky = W)
        Label(self,text = "Choose the options which you feel are correct.").grid(row = 1,column = 0,columnspan = 2,sticky = W)

        Label(self,text = "Name :- ").grid(row = 2,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.n_entry = Entry(self)
        self.n_entry.grid(row = 2,column = 1,sticky = W)

        Label(self,text = "Colleges :- ").grid(row = 3,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.cont_college = StringVar()
        colleges = ["Medicaps","Acropolis","SVCE"]
        colum = 1
        for college in colleges:
            Radiobutton(self,text = college,variable = self.cont_college,value = college).grid(row = 3,column = colum,sticky = W)
            colum += 1

        Label(self,text = "Badass teachers :- ").grid(row = 4,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.cont_neelam = BooleanVar()
        self.cont_kautuk = BooleanVar()
        self.cont_jeetu = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,text = "Neelam Dubey",variable = self.cont_neelam).grid(row = 4,column = 1,sticky = W)
        Checkbutton(self,text = "Kautuk Sharma",variable = self.cont_kautuk).grid(row = 4,column = 2,sticky = W)
        Checkbutton(self,text = "Jitendra bhawsar",variable = self.cont_jeetu).grid(row = 4,column = 3,sticky = W)

        Label(self,text = "Affiliation :- ").grid(row = 5,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.cont_aff = StringVar()
        affiliation = ["Medicaps","DAVV","Anna University","RGPV"]
        colum = 1
        for aff in affiliation:
            Radiobutton(self,text = aff,value = aff,variable = self.cont_aff).grid(row = 5,column = colum,sticky = W)
            colum += 1

        Label(self,text = "Raggers :- ").grid(row = 6,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.r_entry = Entry(self)
        self.r_entry.grid(row = 6,column = 1,sticky = W)

        Label(self,text = "How do you feel :- ").grid(row = 7,column = 0,sticky = W)
        self.f_text = Text(self,width = 35,height = 26,wrap = WORD)
        self.f_text.grid(row = 7,column = 1,columnspan = 2)

        Button(self,text = "Click for story ",command = self.reveal).grid(row = 8,column = 0,sticky = W)

        self.text = Text(self,width = 35,height = 26,wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 9,column = 0,columnspan = 2,sticky = W)

    def reveal(self):

        name = self.n_entry.get()
        college = self.cont_college.get()
        teachers = ""
        if self.cont_neelam.get():
            teachers += "Neelam Dubey, "
        if self.cont_kautuk.get():
            teachers += "Kautuk Sharma, "
        if self.cont_jeetu.get():
            teachers += "Jeetendra Bhawsar "

        affiliation = self.cont_aff.get()
        raggers = self.r_entry.get()
        feel = self.f_text.get()
        self.f_text.delete()

        story = "Once opon a time there was a college named " + college.title() + " .Which was affiliated to " + affiliation + "."
        story += "There were some badass teachers in it, whose names were " + teachers + "."
        story += "Every year some students took admission in it ,but one day an extraordinary student took admission ."
        story += "The name of the student was " + name + "."
        story += "And this is what he felt about the college ,' " + feel + " '."
        story += "\nTHATS ALL FOLKS....."

        self.text.delete(0.0,END)
        self.text.insert(0.0,story)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x250")
    root.title("Medicaps ki paathshala")

    frame = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: `get()` on a Text widget requires start and end position arguements

Comment: Hm, got it ...Thanks .Can i delete this question ??

Comment: That would probably be the best idea as this question is mostly the result of an oversight.